# Rendering Bootstrap modal in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, partial-views

I'm trying to render a modal across multiple pages using a partial view.  For instance: in my View, I have the code:

```
@Html.Partial("_AccountModal")
```

The Account Modal is the name of the view with the modal information. I understand that I could write the code for the modal on every page that I need it on, but this doesn't seem efficient. My controller returns a partial view, however when the code does hit the controller it doesn't return a modal view, it returns a whole page, if that makes sense. Here's the controller code:

```
public ActionResult _AccountModal(string code)
{
    var account = svc.GetSingle(code);
    return PartialView("_AccountModal", account);
}
```

Comment: can you show what is in the _AccountModal partial view?

Comment: We'll definitely need to see the partial view code to be sure. But it could be that you need to add your script/style statements (whether you are using bundles or <script src../> at the top of the partial view page.